# Как сделать обработчик кнопок в уведомлении Android

Tags: java, android

Как через кнопку в уведомлении запущенное из службы вызвать метод processIntent() в MainActivity (обработчик кнопок). В уведомлении я прописал кнопки

```
        Intent stopIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        stopIntent.putExtra(STOP, true);
        stopIntent.setAction(STOP);

        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.button)
            .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_launcher))
            .setContentTitle("My appka")
            .setOngoing(true)
            .addAction(new NotificationCompat.Action(R.drawable.start, "Start", PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, startIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT)))
            .addAction(new NotificationCompat.Action(R.drawable.stop, "Stop", PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, stopIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT)))
            .setContentText("text");
```

В MainActivity у меня такой метод:

```
    private void processIntent(Intent intent){
    if (intent.getAction()!=null){
        switch (intent.getAction()){
            case STOP:
                //коды
                break;

            case START:
                //коды
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

а как дальше вызвать processIntent() в MainActivity ? Или нужно сделать по другому, через Broadcast?

Answer (score 1):

В `onCreate()` вызвать `processIntent(getIntent())`

Comment: нужен запуск метода не через onCreate() при запуске MainActivity, а через кнопки в шторке уведомления